# How to add site speed over the users chart in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, statistics, visitors

I am looking at a default "audience" chart, it shows total users per day, how can I add data over that chart in order to see average page speed ?

So that I can see total users per day vs average page load time and decide if there is a correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Site Speed (as the metric is defined in Analytics) is attributed to pages, not users. You can add the typical secondary dimensions when exploring these statistics, but these dimensions don't include users.

You should be able to get a decent idea of page speeds by whatever metrics might be a deciding factor (new vs returning, for example) by segmenting your data.